# Создание своего контрола в C#. Выбор подходящего предка

Tags: c#, usercontrol

Здравствуйте. Возникла необходимость создать свое собственное бинарное дерево на основе существующих элементов управления C#, но догадок практически нет. Может быть, кто-то уже сталкивался с таким, или знает, как это правильней реализовать?

Как вариант было - создавать на основе TreeView и какого-либо DataGridView. Причем ДатаГридВью использовать только для перечисления элементов дерева(т.е. для свойства Nodes), а дальше они будут сами упорядочиваться в бинарное. Хотелось бы узнать, насколько верным будет использовать такую концепцию? Что было бы лучше сделать? И, простите, куда надо писать код упорядочивания?)

Comment: Вы не должны смотреть на удобство наследования. Смотрите на смысл. Наследование — средство выражения отношения _is-a_. Для повторного использования готовых контролов, включите их в свой `UserControl`.

Comment: По сути, необходим TreeView, у каждого узла которого может быть только две ветки максимум. Но я никак не разберусь, что лучше сделать: отнаследоваться, и каким-то образом ограничить количество возможных ветвей, или же сделать композицию, собственноручно создать свойство nodes, изучив материал по редакторам коллекций? Больше не вижу возможностей, и хотелось бы узнать, насколько реальны эти варианты

Comment: @lester: Реальны оба, но правильно конечно же композиция. Иначе у вас будет экспортировано свойство `ItemsSource`, а вам нужно по существу лишь `LeftChild` и `RightChild` в `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Comment: В целом результат успешен, спасибо за подсказку.

Приблизительное описание того, что у меня получилось, мб кому-то пригодится:

Получился элемент управления, содержащий в себе TreeView. Я добавила лишь одно новое свойство-Nodes. Для его редактирования использую редактор-наследник UITypeEditor. При изменении свойства вызывается форма, ей в качестве параметра передается бинарное дерева(пришлось писать класс), и согласно ей рисуется дерево для дальнейшего редактирования. После редактирования форма возвращает дерево в мой компонент. Тут, по идее, дерево должно отрисоваться уже на компоненте.

Comment: Вот и отлично. Удачи вам!

Comment: Осталась единственна проблема: как при установке свойства сделать так, чтобы изменения отображались на моем компоненте? Я делаю так:
        public myTree result
        {
            get {return localTree;}
            set
            {
                localTree = value;
                this.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
                localTree.print(this.treeView1);
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
, но ничего не происходит. Уже много чего изучила, но не нашла, что для этого нужно. Не подскажете, что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: @lester: может, лучше задайте отдельный вопрос? И приведите кусочек кода. В формате комментариев это сложно обсуждать.